# python calling arguments of function into another script

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to call arguments of one function into another script. But I keep getting error. Below is the code:
the input is a text file for the below function.

script1.py

```
def regex_parameters(value, arg):

    a = re.search(r'\d{1}-\d{1}', value)

    b = re.search(r'\d{1}-\d{1}', value)

    c = re.search(r'\d{1,4}( \w+){1,6},( \w+){1,3}\s\d{1,6}', value)

    d = re.search(r'\(?\b[2-9][0-9]{2}\)?[-. ]?[2-9][0-9]{2}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b', value)

    date = re.search(r'[A-z]{3,10}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}', value)

    return(value, arg)
```

script2.py

```
import script 1
from script1 import *

for i in arg:
    identity = regex_parameters(value, i)
    if value is not None:
        print(i, ":", value.group())
    else:
        clean = ""
```

i would like the output to be:

```
a = output of regex
b = output of regex
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please add the error output to your problem.

Comment: NameError: name 'arg' is not defined

Comment: i am sure i am doing a mistake in calling, but not sure - where the problem is! arg should take the values a,b,c,d and value is the search part of regex from text.
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't defined variable `arg` before the point when it is accessed in:

```
for i in arg: <---
    ...
```

Do something like this:

```
arg = [... , ... , ...]
for i in arg: <---
    ...
```

Another thing, `value` doesn't have a '.group()', because value is still a .

You assume `value` to be a [`Match Object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), because that's what `re.search()` [returns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), but you have never did `value = re.search(...)`.

Comment: i am calling the variable text as:  identity = regex_parameters(text, i)

please note: text is a variable defined in script1.py

the error i get is:
NameError: name 'arg' is not defined

Comment: Edited my answer, please, put the entire error in your question. People really appreciate it in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to parse command-line arguments you must import the sys package `import sys` in `script2.py`.
Instead of `arg` at `for i in arg:` you must write `for i in sys.argv:`
the result should be like this:

```
import script1
import sys
from script1 import *

for i in sys.argv:
    identity = regex_parameters(value, i)
    if value is not None:
        print(i, ":", value.group())
    else:
        clean = ""
```

Note that the first argument in `sys.argv` is going to be the filename, so if you want to avoid that you should splice the first argument like so: `sys.argv[1:]`

More on parsing [Command-line arguments in Python](https://gist.github.com/dideler/2395703)